# Get elements whose display is block

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing a chrome extension where I working on a webpage which lists some things. So, basically, I am reading that table and doing some calculation in the javascript and showing them. Now, there is a filter option on the webpage. After filtering, it doesn't show some things on the list according to the filter selected. And it does so, by making the display as none. It makes the display as none by doing something like below:

```
[data-assignee]:not([data-aggr-assignees*="|xyz|"]) {
    display: none;
}
```

So, when I am trying to find the elements whose display is not none to see the filtered items, it is giving all items since looks like it is not changing the CSS property of the items. I checked the style.display values of all the elements and it is coming '' for all. Can someone help me in how can I get the elements whose display is block in this kind of case?

Comment: Should a `display: block` element inside a `display: none` element be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query selector the whole document with `*` and go through each element with a `for` loop to check if its inline `display` property is set to none. Of course, this will only handle cases when the element is hidden with inline CSS.

```html
<div style="display: block;">
DIV
</div>
<span style="display: none;"></span>
<script>
var allElems = document.querySelectorAll("*");
var visibleElems = [];
var hiddenElems = [];
for(let i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++){
  if(allElems[i].style.display != "none"){
    visibleElems.push(allElems[i]);
  } else {
   hiddenElems.push(allElems[i]);
  }
}
console.log("Visible elements: "+visibleElems);
console.log("Hidden elements: "+hiddenElems);
</script>
```

If you want to check the `display` property of the elements from the CSS stylesheet, you will need to use `window.getComputedStyle`.

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block;">
DIV
</div>
<textarea class="hidden"></textarea>
<span style="display: none;"></span>
<style>
</style>
<div class="hidden">
</div>
<select class="hidden"></select>
<script>
var allElems = document.querySelectorAll("*");
var visibleElems = [];
var hiddenElems = [];
for(let i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++){
  if(allElems[i].style.display == "none"||window.getComputedStyle(allElems[i], null).getPropertyValue("display")=="none"){
    hiddenElems.push(allElems[i]);
  } else {
   visibleElems.push(allElems[i]);
  }
}
console.log("Visible elements: "+visibleElems);
console.log("Hidden elements: "+hiddenElems);
</script>
```